# Linux kernel 3.9 KVM for ARM processor

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kvm

Linux kernel 3.9 support ARM processor for KVM. (http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.9)

There should be CPU H/W support for KVM such as Intel VT or AMD-V. So, my questions are:

- What kind of ARM processors can be used for KVM?
- What ARM technologies enables KVM on ARM?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this information from Linux kernel commits (http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=749cf76c5a363e1383108a914ea09530bfa0bd43).

- Only supported core is Cortex-A15 for now.

And, ARM Coretex A15 provides H/W Virtualization Extension and LPAE(Large Physical Address Extension). Please see [this document](http://xen.org/files/xensummit_seoul11/nov2/2_XSAsia11_JGoodacre_HW_accelerated_virtualization_in_the_ARM_Cortex_processors.pdf) for more information.

I collected some [related information](http://androidkr.blogspot.kr/2013/05/linux-kernel-v39-arm-kvm.html) in my blog. It's written in Korean, but you can use Google translate.